# Where is my mistake in this integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, real-numbers

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{e^t} dt $$ 
The above integral can be computed to be exactly 1 with integration by parts. 
However, i just wanted to try different integration techniques to see if i could arrive at the same result.

So i carry the following substitution $ t = \ln(k) $ and end up with the following integral 
$$ \int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{\ln(k)}{k^2} dk $$ 
I plug this integral into WolframAlpha and i am told that it does not converge.

Please note that i would never do this substitution under normal circumstances i am just messing around with integrals.

So my question is, where did i make the mistake? Did i mess up my integration boundaries?

Comment: I get the limits $\int_1^\infty$.

Comment: could you please take me through how you got that? Noting that upon checking with Wolfram it is correct

Comment: $k=e^t:[0,+\infty)\to[1,+\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

One way of evaluating this integral is noting that 
$$\Gamma(n)=\int_0^\infty t^{n-1}e^{-t}dt$$
And for non-negative integer $n$, $$\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!$$
Which gives your integral $$\Gamma(2)=1!=1$$
QED

Comment: $$\Gamma(n)=\int_0^{\infty} t^{\color{red}{n-1}}e^{-t} dt$$

Comment: @Digamma Oop! fixing it!